# Optimization of SQL with subquery and Having

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Currently we are using a custom CI library to generate PDF files from documents which exist as database records in our database.

Each document is related to the contents (== rows) with a one-has-many relation. Each row has a number (field: row_span) to indicate how many lines it will use once it gets printed in the PDF.

Per PDF page that gets build, Rows needed for that page only are selected using a subquery:

```
$where = $this->docType."_id = ".$this->data['doc']->id." AND visible = 1";
$sql = "SELECT *,

    (SELECT
    sum(row_span) FROM app_".$this->docType."_rows X
    WHERE X.position <= O.position 
    AND ".$where." 
    ORDER BY position ASC) 'span_total'

    FROM app_".$this->docType."_rows O 
    WHERE ".$where."
    HAVING span_total > ".(($i-1)*$this->maxRows)." AND span_total <= ".($i*$this->maxRows)." ORDER BY O.position ASC ";

$rows = $rows->query($sql);
```

In the code `$i` is the page number and `$this->maxRows` is loaded from the document template record which indicates how many available lines the PDF template has.

So when the SQL renders it might look like this for page 1 of an order with ID 834:

```
SELECT `app_order_rows`.*, 
(SELECT SUM(`app_order_rows_subquery`.`row_span`) AS row_span
    FROM `app_order_rows` `app_order_rows_subquery`
    WHERE `app_order_rows_subquery`.`position` <= 'app_order_rows.position'
    AND `app_order_rows_subquery`.`order_id` =  834
    AND `app_order_rows_subquery`.`visible` =  1
    ORDER BY `app_order_rows_subquery`.`position` asc) AS span_total 
FROM (`app_order_rows`) 
WHERE `app_order_rows`.`order_id` =  834
AND `app_order_rows`.`visible` =  1
HAVING span_total >  0
AND span_total <=  45
ORDER BY `app_order_rows`.`position` asc
```

And running this with EXPLAIN gives this as output:

```
+====+=============+=========================+======+===============+======+=========+======+======+=============================+===+
| id | select_type | table                   | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                       |   |
+====+=============+=========================+======+===============+======+=========+======+======+=============================+===+
| 1  | PRIMARY     | app_order_rows          | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1809 | Using where; Using filesort | 1 |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+---+
| 2  | SUBQUERY    | app_order_rows_subquery | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1809 | Using where                 | 2 |
+====+=============+=========================+======+===============+======+=========+======+======+=============================+===+
```

This is working great, but... When we have large orders or invoices it renders the documents very slow. This might be due to the subquery.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do the same select without subquery? Maybe we will have to go for a whole new approach to select rows and build the PDF. We are open for suggestions ^^

Thanks in advance

------------------------------- edit ------------------------------

The EXPLAIN after index creation:

```
+====+=============+=========================+=======+===============+============+=========+=======+======+=============+===+
| id | select_type | table                   | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |   |
+====+=============+=========================+=======+===============+============+=========+=======+======+=============+===+
| 1  | PRIMARY     | app_order_rows          | ref   | index_main    | index_main | 5       | const | 9    | Using where | 1 |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+---+
| 2  | SUBQUERY    | app_order_rows_subquery | range | index_main    | index_main | 10      | NULL  | 1    | Using where | 2 |
+====+=============+=========================+=======+===============+============+=========+=======+======+=============+===+
```

Comment: Can you please post this as a SQL query, so we don't have to parse your PHP in our heads? And can you execute this SQL and get an EXPLAIN, so we can see what the real problem is? And can you please post a schema, so we can see whether you have any indexing already?

Comment: Most of it is SQL :) I'll update the question on my next break :D

Comment: '... it renders the documents very slow. This might be due to the subquery.'  Did you monitor this behavior or are you just guessing?

Comment: @Philipp I read it searching for a possible reason.

Comment: @NevilleK I did the update and added a few things.

Comment: It looks like there aren't any indexes on the tables - is that true?

Comment: @NevilleK Yes there are no indexes on the rows tables. DB management isn't our top skill :p

Answer (score 1):

As you confirmed in the comments, the tables have no indexes.

The immediate solution would be:

```
create index index_main on app_order_rows (order_id, position);
```

Comment: I hoped it would be solved with simple index creation but it isn't.

Comment: can you post the EXPLAIN after creating the index?

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: Okay - the EXPLAIN shows that it's using the index; it should be MUCH faster now. Are you sure the problem is in the SQL, and not the PHP? Can you please run the query in a command line with and without indexes, and see what the timings are?

Comment: When I execute the SQL with the indexes it takes  0.0013 sec, which is fast. And 0.0022 without the indexes. The loading of the PDF takes up to 20 seconds. It might be a problem in PHP I guess. Most of the documents open fast (almost instant) though...

Comment: In that case, it's definitely not the SQL where you should be optimizing - it's either PHP or infrastructure. PDF generation can be very memory intensive - perhaps large documents go beyond your web server's memory limits?

Comment: Okay - we'll investigate the library all night long if we have to ... Thanks for your help